# Auto create documents on firestore when I change profile

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I have the code below that add to a random document, after pressing a button, the information that I need for my app.

In this case I need to create this documents and on the homepage I need to get the value of this docs, BUT I have a problem, when I create the first one is okay, after that when I change the account to verify that all function correctly and I'm going make the second request with a different account(so create the second doc) on homepage I find more than one request that I recently made with first account, and these request have a timestamp equal to the logged in on the second account. How can I fix it?

Code to add datas on Firestore

```
Future AggiungiCampi () async {
      final User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
      final String? uid = user?.uid;
          QuerySnapshot query = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('utenti').where('uid', isEqualTo: uid).get();
          QueryDocumentSnapshot doc = query.docs[0];
          DocumentReference docRef = doc.reference;
          DocumentReference docRef1 = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('contatore').doc();
          DocumentReference docRef3 = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('contatoreD').doc();
          if(query.docs[0]['Sesso'] == 'Uomo') {
            docRef1.set({
              'Prenotato': true,
              'Prenotazione': FieldValue.increment(1),
              'Creazione': Timestamp.now(),
              'Tempo': _scelta,
              'uid': user?.uid,
              'url': doc['url'],
              'Nome': doc['Nome'],
              'Sesso': doc['Sesso'],

            }).whenComplete(() {
              showDialog(
                  context: context,
                  builder: (BuildContext context) {
                  return AlertDialog(
                      title: const Text('Prenotazione effettuata',
                        style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontSize: 20,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                      ),),
                      backgroundColor: Color(0xFFf6f6f6),
                      content: const Text('La richiesta di prenotazione è stata effettuata correttamente',
                    style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black,),),
                      actions: [
                        TextButton(
                          style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                            foregroundColor: Color(0xFFE5332A),
                          ),
                          child: const Text('Conferma'),
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.of(context).pop();
                          },
                        ),
                      ],
                    );
                  }

              );

            });
          } else if (query.docs[0]['Sesso'] == 'Donna'){
            docRef3.set({
              'Prenotato': true,
              'Prenotazione': FieldValue.increment(1),
              'Creazione': Timestamp.now(),
              'Tempo': _scelta,
              'uid': user?.uid,
              'url': query.docs[0]['url'],
              'Nome': query.docs[0]['Nome'],
              'Sesso': query.docs[0]['Sesso'],

            }).whenComplete(() {
              showDialog(
                  context: context,
                  builder: (BuildContext context) {
                    return AlertDialog(
                      title: const Text('Prenotazione effettuata'),
                      content: const Text('La richiesta di prenotazione è stata effettuata correttamente'),
                      actions: [
                        TextButton(
                          style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                            foregroundColor: const Color(0xFFE5332A),
                          ),
                          child: const Text('Conferma'),
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.of(context).pop();
                          },
                        ),
                      ],
                    );
                  }

              );

            });
          }
        }
>! Code of the button that call the function
ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: (){
                            AggiungiCampi();
                          },
                          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                            backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                            minimumSize: const Size(250, 50),
                          ),
                          child: const Text('Conferma la prenotazione', style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                            fontSize: 18,
                            ),
                          ),
                       ),
```

Comment: Shortly, when I log in with a different account it automatically generate new document also if I’m on homepage and I not click on the button